# Multiple EJB files, "loader constraint violation" error with JBoss/Wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, wildfly

I have a something.ear file like this:

```
META-INF
something-ejb.jar
something-rest.jar
geolocation.jar
```

And `application.xml` is like:

```
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd" version="7">
  <display-name>discripto-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>something-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>geolocation.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>something-rest.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/rest</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

I have a `Location.java` class in `geolocation.jar`. When I run this part of code in `something-rest.jar`:

```
    // locationService is stateless EJB in geolocation.jar
    final Location location = this.locationService.getLocation(getIp(request));

    // taskService is stateless EJB in something-ejb.jar
    this.taskService.nextTaskScript(location);
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "com.wpic.discripto.service.TaskService.nextTaskScript(Lcom/wpic/geo/Location;)Lcom/wpic/discripto/service/TaskWithScript;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, com/wpic/discripto/rest/Tasks, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for resolved class, com/wpic/discripto/service/TaskService, have different Class objects for the type geo/Location;)Lcom/wpic/discripto/service/TaskWithScript; used in the signature
```

I'm sure there's just one instance of class Location.java in all EJBs and libraries.

I'm using Wildfly 9.0.1 and Java7/Maven to compile my code. Any idea?

Comment: Are you using manifest class path entries? Your application.xml does not seem to match up with the EAR structure you provide beforehand.

Comment: Sorry I typed it wrong, now I fixed it.

Comment: It looks like you have either the dependency in there twice or two classes with the same name.

Comment: I don't have two instances, my app is very tiny, just 2 jar files and one war file, no dependencies! It's very easy to check if It has duplicate class or not.

Comment: I think what's happening is that you've modified your `Location.java` file and forgot to update or the module that contains `com/wpic/discripto/rest/Tasks` or the module that contains `com/wpic/discripto/service/TaskService`. Since `Location.java` is only present (according to you) on `geolocation.jar`, some of the other modules  **do have dependencies** for it.